# Audio Player not appearing when trying to play audio file (wav) stored in client machine in google chrome in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, html, google-chrome, audio

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm11.aspx.cs" Inherits="omos.WebForm11" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <object data="file:\\\n:\test\abc.wav" style="width: 100px" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My ASP page will call the above html page. It work well in IE (the audio player appeared and start to play), but for google chrome, the audio player doesn't appear. The audio file n:\test\abc.wav is stored in another file server (i.e. n drive is not the Web Server). If I store the audio files in the web server, both IE and Google Chrome work fine, but my audio files have to be in another server. 
Why IE can work and Google Chrome cannot (same code), why like that? I am headache, any one got Panadol?

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work:
Note: We have checked in IE 10 & latest version. May not support in IE-8/9. Please excuse.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript">

        var activeobj = 0;
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            document.write("<object data='horse.wav' style='width:400px;' />");
        } else {
            document.write("<audio controls><source src='horse.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'> Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>");
        }
 </script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```